# Kubectl create multiline secret

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I'm trying to put a Service Account into a secret - I did it previously a year ago and it works but now - no matter how I approach it, the application doesn't see it right and says there is `Input byte array has incorrect ending byte` - When creating normal secret I know you've gotta do it with a new line so

```sh
echo -n "secret" | base64
```

and put that value in secret and apply, but my multiline file

```sh
cat secret.json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "smth-smth",
  "private_key_id": "blabla"
...
}
```

No matter how I approach - whether put it by hand like in the first example, or do it with

```sh
cat secret.json | base64

# or 

base64 < secret.json
```

the secret is created but application throws

```sh
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 3104
```

When I compare the new secret to the last one of the service account the difference is how the output looks like

The working one is smth like this - when I try to decrypt the base64

```sh
echo -n "<long string of base64 encrypred sa> | base64 -D
    { "type": "service_account", "project_id": "blabla"... }
```

so it's in one line, and the new SA I try to decrypt is outputed in the format as in the file - so each part of json in new line - I tried manually putting it all in one line but without success

Anyone know ? how to put a multiline file in a secret (base64) properly?

Comment: Are you using `Google Kubernetes Engine` - Cloud provider or you just using Kubernetes? What Kubernetes version are you using? How are you creating this secret?

Comment: yea GKE, just plain base64 from variables put into a secret straight from docs no magic there, did the format of secrets change that much in kuberentes version ? running latest or maybe month old version so dont think that's the issue

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to create a secret from a file is to use `kubectl create secret generic`.

Put your file `secret.json` in a folder `config` and then run:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=config
```

You will get a secret `my-secret` with one key `secret.json` containing your file (which you can then mount to a pod volume).

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create files an option is to write into a variable and then load the result into a `--file-literal`. This may be necessary because it seems `kubectl` either escapes newline characters `\n` when inside a quoted string and ignores them if no quotes are supplied. When reading from a variable the `\n`are treated as expected.

EDIT: With regards to multi-line strings do take care to use correct linefeed characters, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72116382/what-is-the-difference-of-writing-to-files-using-vs-using-linefeed-characte/72116477#72116477). I ran into that when trying my answer at home :)

```
target_string=$(echo "string1\nstring2")
kubectl create secret generic your-secret-name --from-literal=your_key=$target_string
```