# What is the difference of writing to files using ">>" vs using linefeed character "\n" in a string when loading text to Kubernetes secret?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, unix, zsh, kubectl

I have observed that `kubectl` inserts an additional `\` to linefeed characters when using the `--from-literal` option. It works as expected when loading "the same" content from a file. Clearly, there must be a difference because the stdout looks different but I fail to see why.

```
echo "api_key" >> .tmp
echo "api_value" >> .tmp
cat -e .tmp
kubectl delete secrets api-env
kubectl create secret generic api-env --from-file=.api=.tmp
rm .tmp
kubectl get secret api-env -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'

#prints:
#api_key$
#api_value$
#secret "api-env" deleted
#secret/api-env created
#{
#  ".api": "api_key\napi_value\n"
#}
```

The commands above create a single linefeed character on each line. Demonstrated by `cat -e` there are two linefeed characters in the file, each at the end.

Doing the same using a string results in the `\n` to be escaped.

```
api="api_key\napi_value\n"
echo $api
kubectl delete secrets api-env
kubectl create secret generic api-env --from-literal=.api=$api
kubectl get secret api-env -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'

#prints:
#api_key\napi_value\n
#secret "api-env" deleted
#secret/api-env created
#{
#  ".api": "api_key\\napi_value\\n"
#}
```

The `echo` command shows the string as it was supplied to the variable, however after loading that to kubernetes the `\n` are escaped and the content is considered to be a single line.

This is important because in several instances where I am working with `kubectl` I am not allowed to write to the local file system.

What is happening here and how to stop kubernetes from escaping the `\n` character?

Environment:

- zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
- Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
- kubectl Client:"v1.20.10"
- kubectl Server: "v1.23.3"
- minikube version: v1.25.2

Comment: The POSIX specification for `echo` does not specify its behavior when you put `\n`s in the sequence, and different versions behave different ways. It's *far* more reliable to use `printf` instead -- this advice is even given by [the official `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)! ([Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) over on [unix.se] also goes into `echo`'s problems in long-form detail).

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "api_key" "api_value" >.tmp` in particular is a good place to start.

Comment: ...of course, with an extended shell like bash or zsh, you can also use `--from-file=<(printf '%s\n' "api_key" "api_value")` and not have a _real_ file on disk at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `echo $api`, `echo` itself changes the contents: On POSIX-compliant shells with XSI extensions enabled (and while zsh isn't POSIX-compliant in general, it *does* implement this aspect), the `\n`s are replaced with literal newlines.

That *doesn't* happen with `--from-literal=.api=$api`; there, your `\n`s are still two-character sequences, first a backslash, then a `n`.

Given that you're on a shell that supports using `$'\n'` as a way to represent a newline literal directly, consider `--from-literal=.api="api_key"$'\n'"api_value"`

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. the ``$'\n'``made it work like a charm. Oh and it is ``--from-literal``:) Too bad that this behavior is shell specific... one more reason to avoid ``zsh`` (-: